# Is better sync or async from boost asio when there is lot of calculation and push/pop on thread safe containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

Need advice on `boost::asio` because I am totally new and have deadline soon, I need to create a TCP server (lot of connections)  and I used the [chat server example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_server.cpp) from the documentation as a start point.

When I receive a message I have lot of calculation over and I need to push in thread-safe queue (lock guard mutex). Except writing and reading everything calculates in main thread ( where callback executes ?). For this purpose do I need to put synchronous with lot  of threads maybe or is there any rule how to make async with lot of calculations quicker ?

(I can put calculation in new  async but I wonder is there better solution )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just handle the communication asynchronously, on a single thread. This should allow up to ~10k connections per second. Just **don't perform anything slow** on this thread. Just push onto the queue and yield to the communication service.

Now, start as many threads as can usefully do the CPU intensive work (usually #of logical core, but sometimes #physical cores and certainly if you are saturating the communication throughput (unlikely), may (#cores - 1)).

If you anticipate that the IO side will be saturated and you cannot afford to block even on the mutex, use a lockfree queue. In that case, *definitely* dimension (#cores -1) workers, because the workers would naturally spin in a tight loop waiting for messages on the queue, suffocating the IO thread if you don't take precautions.